# HTML+CSS?+JS Слайдер текста

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, slider

Есть шаблон сайта: http://demo.flytheme.net/themes/sm_style/index.php/
Там сверху есть слайдер текста:

[image: скриншот]

Т.е. после иконки самолетика текст плавно сдвигается влево, а справа плавно выезжает другой текст.

Вопрос в том, как сделать это самостоятельно. Я не использую библиотеки для этого проекта, т.к. хочу именно повысить свои знания в области web(html,css,js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С тем же эффектом промотки обратно, как на указанном сайте)))
Хотя на самом деле это косяк :D

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 2em;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  background: silver;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

section:before {
  content: "";
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin: .25em;
  float: left;
  background: url(//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style: none;
  animation: slide-8 40s linear infinite;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes slide-8 {
   0.0% { transform: translateX(   0 ) }
  10.0% { transform: translateX(   0 ) }
  12.5% { transform: translateX(-100%) }
  22.5% { transform: translateX(-100%) }
  25.0% { transform: translateX(-200%) }
  35.0% { transform: translateX(-200%) }
  37.5% { transform: translateX(-300%) }
  47.5% { transform: translateX(-300%) }
  50.0% { transform: translateX(-400%) }
  60.0% { transform: translateX(-400%) }
  62.5% { transform: translateX(-500%) }
  72.5% { transform: translateX(-500%) }
  75.0% { transform: translateX(-600%) }
  85.0% { transform: translateX(-600%) }
  87.5% { transform: translateX(-700%) }
  97.5% { transform: translateX(-700%) }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Первый пункт
      <li>Второй
      <li>И третий
      <li>Ещё один
      <li>И пятый
      <li>Шестой
      <li>Седьмой
      <li>Ну и хватит
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

> В хроме отлично работает, не могу понять в чем косяк ))

Я про перемотку от последнего пункта к первому. Обычно делается прокрутка в одну сторону, а тут получается в обратную очень быстро всё проматывается.

> да, я обратил внимание, есть идеи как это исправить?? )

Если не использовать скрипты, то наиболее удобный вариант - сделать первый и последний пункты одинаковыми и добавить точку 100%. Тогда переход со 100 на 0 будет незаметен для пользователя, поскольку содержимое одинаково.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 2em;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  background: silver;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

section:before {
  content: "";
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin: .25em;
  float: left;
  background: url(//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style: none;
  animation: slide-8 40s linear infinite;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes slide-8 {
   0.0% { transform: translateX(   0 ) }
  10.0% { transform: translateX(   0 ) }
  12.5% { transform: translateX(-100%) }
  22.5% { transform: translateX(-100%) }
  25.0% { transform: translateX(-200%) }
  35.0% { transform: translateX(-200%) }
  37.5% { transform: translateX(-300%) }
  47.5% { transform: translateX(-300%) }
  50.0% { transform: translateX(-400%) }
  60.0% { transform: translateX(-400%) }
  62.5% { transform: translateX(-500%) }
  72.5% { transform: translateX(-500%) }
  75.0% { transform: translateX(-600%) }
  85.0% { transform: translateX(-600%) }
  87.5% { transform: translateX(-700%) }
  97.5% { transform: translateX(-700%) }
 100.0% { transform: translateX(-800%) }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Первый пункт
      <li>Второй
      <li>И третий
      <li>Ещё один
      <li>И пятый
      <li>Шестой
      <li>Седьмой
      <li>Ну и хватит
      <li>Первый пункт <!-- ещё раз -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Ещё можно попробовать добавлять другие анимации, чтобы временно перемещать первый пункт в конец, но я не уверен, всегда ли и во всех ли браузерах анимации сработают достаточно синхронно, чтобы это осталось незамеченным для пользователя.

Ещё, теоретически, в css есть отображение элемента в другое место (даже два способа - как картинка (`background: -moz-element(...)`) и просто перенаправление потока рендеринга (не помню, как сделать, никто не поддерживает). Но, во-первых, оба способа не подходят из-за кроссбраузерности, а во-вторых, первый способ не позволит пользователю взаимодействовать с содержимым блока.

Comment: А почему косяк?? ) Вроде работает

Comment: В хроме отлично работает, не могу понять в чем косяк ))

Comment: @Евгений, я про перемотку от последнего пункта к первому. Обычно делается прокрутка в одну сторону, а тут получается в обратную очень быстро всё проматывается.

Comment: да, я обратил внимание, есть идеи как это исправить?? )

Comment: @Евгений, ответ дополнен.

Comment: @Евгений, а ещё я первый раз забыл `infinite` указать у анимации - тоже поправил.

Answer (score 1):

В таком случае вот вам ответ подсказка:

- Есть блок контейнер с фиксированной шириной и `overflow: hidden`
- Внутри блока элементы стоящие в линию.
- Элементы перемещается по таймеру.

Comment: Примерно так я и думал, но я не плохо разбираюсь в php... java/android. И вот решил набраться знаний в web разработке. Было бы отлично или примеры реализации, в коде я разберусь наверное, или хотя бы ссылки на адекватную информацию... недолгий поиск в google отсылает на всяческие библиотеки, а я хочу научится реализовывать подобное сам. Спасибо!

Comment: @Евгений в любой непонятной ситуации нажимайте F12 и смотрите на элемент через отладку Chrome. Судя по классам в элементе - для слайдера используется [**Owl карусель**](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)

Comment: Да тут вообще js не особо нужен...

Comment: Если JS не нужен, это еще лучше. Хорошо было бы, что бы решение было кросбраузерным и так же работало на мобилках. Не нужен js, это в том плане, что лучше меньше кода :)